# How to set map[string]string value in GoLand when debugging a golang program?

Tags: debugging, goland

I hava use goland dehug，i want to set a value for map[string]string,but i am not set ok

[image: 1]

how to I set the value, i dont know this

[image: 2]

i can set the map[string]string value

Comment: Map evaluation is not available in Delve, please see: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1465